# Wordpress theme on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have installed a theme on a WordPress page running on `localhost`, but I get this error:

> wp_remote_get() failed. Some theme features may not work. Please contact your hosting provider and make sure that https://build.envato.com/api/ is not blocked.
>
> wp_remote_post() failed. Some theme features may not work. Please contact your hosting provider and make sure that https://envato.com/ is not blocked.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Try to locate your `php.ini` file and look for `allow_url_include = Off`.
Change it to `allow_url_include = On`.

Comment: It's already on I read it on some other site but still dosen't work

Comment: Well, maybe try to change the `https` to `http` and see if it works.